# Xcode 4 archive problems with code signing

Tags: xcode, archive, signing

I can't get the archives to work because the message that code signing errors occur returns. It works fine when I build and run on my simulator but not when archiving

Comment: you should edit your question to explain what kinds of errors you're getting (e.g. copy & paste something from the build log, for example).

Comment: Cheers for the fast reply, ok I will it says--- the identy iPhone developer does not match any specific cetificate/private keypair

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things that could be going wrong here so you'd need to solve this step by step.

1)  Open up the Keychain Viewer app in "`/Applications/Utilities/`" and make sure the public & private key you set up for use with your Apple Developer account is there.  If it is not, go get it from the machine you originally set up your account upon (or, you'll need to recreate your public & private key).

2)  Create a provisioning profile for your app on the iTunes Provisioning Portal.  This creates a certificate which allows your apps to be run on your iDevices.  Download the certificate and install it into Xcode.  Newer versions of Xcode automate this process in the Organizer, I believe.

When I have problems like the one you are describing, I go to [Apple's iOS Provisoning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) and along the right side of the main window ("Portal Resources") are "How-To's" with step by step guides on what you need to do to get set up and properly working.  Sometimes in the past I've literally had to start from scratch.  Provisioning and code signing are major pains to get set up properly, but Apple has been working on making this easier and easier with each new release of iOS and Xcode.

Comment: Thanks Michael, really appreciate it!